# Problemas con el centrado de parrafos de texto cuando desbordan el contenedor

Tags: html, css, responsive

Quiero controlar el texto cuando se desborda de su contenedor por ser muy largo y que en el caso de que no se desborde se quede centrado pero no consigo hacer las dos cosas a la vez. Alguna idea?

```css
.justify {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.paragraph {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 220px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  text-align-last: left; 

  
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Hola, esto es un texto muy pero que muy largo</p>
</div>

<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Hola, esto es la palabra externomascloideo que no quiero se divida</p>
</div>

<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Esto lo quiero centrado!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Y cuando el texto se desborda ¿qué quieres que ocurra exactamente?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes centrar y justificar al mismo tiempo asi:

```css
.justify {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.paragraph {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 220px;
  
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Hola, esto es un texto muy pero que muy largo</p>
</div>

<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Hola, esto es la palabra externomascloideo que no quiero se divida</p>
</div>

<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Esto lo quiero centrado!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Quizás no me he explicado bien. En las dos primeras opciones quiero que no se desborde pero se quede alienado a la izquierda (no lo quiero centrado). En la tercera forma si que lo quiero centrado.

Comment: Los textos son fijos?  Sabes el largo de cada uno?  O son dinamicos y la longitud puede variar?

Comment: No veo la importancia de que el texto sea fijo o dinamico. Son varios textos de longitudes distintas dentro de un contenedor de anchura definida por % . La solución de alancf me valdría si el resultado de los dos primeros recuadros rojo de la ejecución se alineasen a la izquierda y solo el tercero (al ser más corto  que el ancho del contenedor) quedase centrado.